# How to write a linked list properly?

Tags: c, linked-list

I will use `push` to push a string word in `queue q` and instead
of keeping the pointer to the array, it will keeps a COPY of the word inside the `queue`.

This is my code.

```
struct node_struct {
    char *data;
    struct node_struct *next;
};

typedef struct node_struct Node;

struct queue_struct {
    Node *head, *tail;
};

typedef struct queue_struct Queue;
```

```
void push(Queue **q, char *word) 
{
    // q hasn't been allocated
    if (*q == NULL) {
        (*q) = malloc(sizeof(Queue));
    }

    Node *temp;
    temp = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    temp->data = word;
    temp->next = NULL;

    if ((*q)->head == NULL) {
        (*q)->head = (*q)->tail = temp;
    }
    else {
        (*q)->head->tail = temp;
        (*q)->head = temp;
    }
}
```

But it has a problem in this line `(*q)->head->tail = temp;`

It says `struct "node_struct" has no field "tail"`. Does anyone know why this thing occurs and how to fix this?

Comment: Should be `(*q)->head->next = temp;`

Comment: `(*q)` points to a `Queue`.  The `head` field of a `Queue` points to a `Node`, so `(*q)->head` points to a `Node`.  A `Node` has two fields, `data` and `next`.  It has no `tail` field, which is why you're getting an error.  Did you perhaps mean `(*q)->head->next`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confusing the queue with the node. The queue has a head and a tail, but the node has a next pointer. You should be setting (*q)->tail->next = temp; instead.